# Howto deploy an static fileserver built with Go to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, go

I wanted to deploy an simple static file serevr I built to Heroku but it seems as soons as it is deployed to heroku is crashes immediatly...

I never pushed an Go App to Heroku and I bet my ports config isw wrong...

What confuses me is that it passes th build process and it crashes immeditiatly...

I also uploaded the source code to Github: [Sourcecode](https://github.com/norbertfuhs/heroku-go-sample-app)

I bet there are many errors in the code or something I didn't get right with port forwarding at Heroku but any advices or hints would be great!

Comment: Does your file server have a web interface? Heroku expects your application to bind to port 80 and respond to HTTP requests.

Comment: What filesystem does your file server use? Note that Herku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem); anything you write to disk will be lost every time your Dyno restarts, which happens at least once per day.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know I need a web-interface... I will add it to the the app.. I'm currently playing aorund with this app a litlle bit I shall code a simple responsive web app but it must be served with go... I currently have now root server so I thought using heroku would be an easy and fast way to archieve this.. I don't have a credit card so I can't register for services like Azure or AWS...  I just wanted an easy and free go based way to serve static content for testing and rewieving.. Thnks for the help Chris!

Comment: You do not necessarily need a web interface, iirc. You just need to bind to port 80 and respond with a http.StatusOK for `/`